# .net login to a site who use javascript forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

My current .net code (doesn't work) :

```
Dim w As New Net.WebClient
Dim values As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
values.Add("username", "toto")
values.Add("password", "totopassword")
w.UploadValues("http://www.webadresse.com", values)
w.DownloadString("http://webadresse.com")
```

how can i login to this :

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="username">
<input type="text" value="password">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: submitFormMaster();">
</form>
```

And the javascript :

```
var inputUserName = new Ext.form.TextField({
id : "username",
el : "username",
fieldLabel : stringMaster23,
itemCls : "text_authentification",
labelSeparator : "",
allowBlank : false,
autoCreate : {
    tag : "input",
    type : "text",
    size : "18",
    autocomplete : "on",
    maxlength : "50"
}
});
var inputPassword = new Ext.form.TextField({
id : "password",
el : "password",
fieldLabel : stringMaster24,
itemCls : "text_authentification",
labelSeparator : "",
allowBlank : false,
autoCreate : {
    tag : "input",
    type : "password",
    size : "18",
    autocomplete : "on",
    maxlength : "20"
}
});
var radioGroupPrice = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
id : "GroupPrice",
vertical : true,
items : [ {
    name : "displayPrice",
    boxLabel : stringMaster25,
    itemCls : "text_radio_price",
    inputValue : "false"
}, {
    name : "displayPrice",
    boxLabel : stringMaster26,
    itemCls : "text_radio_price",
    inputValue : "true",
    checked : true
} ]
});
var renderSubmit = new Ext.form.Label(
    {
        id : "RenderSubmit",
        name : "RenderSubmit",
        html : '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td align="right" valign="middle"><a href="/ecran/password_lost.asp" class="text_link">'
                + stringMaster27
                + '&nbsp;?</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td width="43" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" onclick="javascript: submitFormMaster();"><img src="'
                + urlBtnOK
                + '" width="43" height="19" title="'
                + stringMaster29
                + '" alt="'
                + stringMaster29
                + '" border="0" /></a></td></tr></table>'
    });
var formMaster = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
id : "FAuthentication",
title : "",
baseCls : "base-cls-override",
cls : "form_authentication_bis",
standardSubmit : true,
frame : true,
width : 210,
labelWidth : 1,
defaultType : "textfield",
items : [ inputUserName, inputPassword, {
    xtype : "fieldset",
    autoHeight : true,
    border : false,
    style : "padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px",
    layout : "column",
    items : [ radioGroupPrice ]
}, renderSubmit ],
keys : [ {
    key : Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
    fn : submitFormMaster
} ],
listeners : {
    afterrender : function() {
        loadFormData();
    }
}
});
function submitFormMaster() {
if (formMaster.getForm().isValid()) {
    if (!formMaster.getForm().getEl().isMasked()) {
        formMaster.getForm().getEl().dom.method = "POST";
        formMaster.getForm().getEl().dom.action = applicationPath
                + currentCulture + "/Authentication";
        formMaster.getForm().submit();
    }
    formMaster.getForm().getEl().mask(stringMaster37);
}
}
function loadFormData() {
if (warnPopupMaster != "") {
    Ext.Msg.alert(stringMaster29Bis, warnPopupMaster);
}
}
Ext.QuickTips.init();
Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = "side";
Ext.onReady(function() {
formMaster.render("AuthenticationForm");
Ext.getCmp("username").focus("", 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is:

```
Request URL:http://www.innelec.com/Corporate/en/Authentication
Request Method:POST
username:aaaaaaa
password:bbbbbbb
displayPrice:true
```

If you want to login and than keep your login status you should add the cookies every request, this is a samlpe class to keep the same cookies every request

```
public class WebClientWithCookies : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer _container = new CookieContainer();
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Method = "Post";
            request.CookieContainer = _container;
        }
        return request;
    }
}

WebClientWithCookies client = new WebClientWithCookies();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31";
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
var result = client.UploadString("http://www.innelec.com/Corporate/en/Authentication", "POST", "username=aaaaaaa&password=bbbbbbb&displayPrice=true");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to send the request to

```
applicationPath + currentCulture + "/Authentication"

http://www.webadresse.com/en/Authentication
```

Comment: otherwise you can use firebug (or chrome developer tools) and see how request is made from that website

Comment: Thanks for help, i give you the real site : www.innelec.com